# how can I use polymer cli v-2.0 with node js and express for making app?

Tags: node.js, express, polymer-2.x

I have installed `polymer-cli` and setup an Express server. How can I run Polymer code with Express?

Comment: Ben Thomas please add contact detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Routing with Polymer and Express](https://wmginsberg.github.io/blog/poly-express) - This link work for you to run **Polymer** code with **Express** and setup **Express**.

```
// Node.js notation for importing packages
var express = require('express');

// Spin up a server
var app = express();

// Serve static files from the main build directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build/bundled'));

// Render index.html on the main page, specify the root
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile("index.html", {root: '.'});
});

// Tell the app to listen for requests on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer given by StackOverflowuser is correct. Just clarifying what I have found so that newbies can follow.

Polymer Cli is a stand alone tool: i.e you don't need anything else to run a polymer app. It has it own web server and listens on the port to serve request.

So when you execute 
`polymer serve --open`
You are serving your polymer app on
 http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/polymer-starter-kit/

Now that you have developed your app, its time to deploy this to a web server as polymer cli is not a web server.

This is the part that requires the deployment.
You now have to build this app to be deployable

We do `polymer build`. This prepares the app for deployment to a separate build folder under

```
build/
    es5-bundled...
```

We now need to take this bundled files and deploy on web server. This is independent of Polymer Cli and you can choose which port etc to expose.

In this case, going by your definition you want to deploy on express which is a web server on top of node.js.

The code present on top explains the actual code you would use to deploy the polymer bundled app in express on top of node.js.

[pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/) abstracts this and you can run it as a service with all the web server goodies. So we could now use pm2 to run the web server app than the default node.js.

Both styles of deployment are possible.

1. Have both web server hosting app and polymer app in the same solution.
2. Have different apps for web server hosting app and polymer app

When you have different apps, you have the added overhead of copying only the files under the build to the web server to be hosted but its cleaner and separates the source from the deployed similar to backed technologies were code is different from compiled libraries.